# AspectJ 'thisJoinPoint' throws exception

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm using AspectJ and the 'ajc' command line compiler. I specify aspectjrt.jar, aspectjtools.jar, and aspectjweaver.jar on the classpath ('-cp') during compilation, yet when I call the standard 'thisJoinPoint', an exception is thrown:

Compilation:

```
ajc -cp lib/aspectjrt.jar:lib/aspectjtools.jar:lib/aspectjweaver.jar -inpath work/src/ -outjar ./mynewjar.jar @work/source.lst
```

Code which causes exception:

```
before() : onCreateCall() {
    System.out.println("[-] PC Info: " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature());
}
```

And the exception itself:

```
Could not find class 'org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.Factory', referenced from method com.test.WooAspects.ajc$preClinit
```

Of course, I've tried specifying the import with the following, but no luck:

```
import org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.Factory;
import org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.*;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling your code, if it references types in a separate library, that library (possibly packaged as a `.jar`) needs to be available on the compilation classpath (`javac` or `ajc` in this case).

When running your code, if it references types in a separate library, that library needs to be available on the runtime classpath (`java` or the alternative for aspectj).

Note that an `import` statement is unrelated to the classpath. All an `import` statement does is allow you to use a type's or member's short name instead of its fully qualified name.

Answer (score 0):

The following things seem to be a little odd at first glance:

- It looks as if you think that `-inpath work/src` actually is meant to include source files, but the inpath is actually meant to include class files. What you probably want is `-sourceroots work/src`.
- Then you seem to use an argument file named `work/source.lst` which you have not shown us, so we do not know what is in there - maybe more command line switches, maybe more source files. I have no idea.
- On your *ajc* classpath there are all three AspectJ libraries, but usually you only need *aspetcjrt.jar*. The other two are only needed for load-time weaving [LTW] (*aspectjtools.jar*) or if you want to use the AspectJ compiler and a few other tools during runtime (*aspectjweaver.jar*).

For a simple project in which Java and AspectJ code are in the same source directory, the following works for me (inserting line breaks for better readability, but it is all one line on the console):

```
ajc
    -1.7
    -cp lib/aspectjrt.jar
    -sourceroots src
    -outjar my.jar
```

Then you run the aspect-enhanced JAR like this (again one line on the console):

```
java
    -cp lib/aspectjrt.jar;my.jar
    de.scrum_master.app.Application
```

I.e. during runtime you also just need the runtime JAR on your classpath.

Maybe you want to use a build tool like Maven managing your dependencies and the build process. You can also use plugins like Maven Shade or One-JAR in order to produce a single über-JAR containing both the compiled Java + AspectJ code and the AspectJ runtime. Then you do not have any problems with classpaths during runtime, you just call

```
java -jar my_uber.jar
```

**Update:** You may want to read the [*ajc* documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ajc-ref.html) for more info.